# Stop auto scrolling of table view when keyboard appears and respective textfield was in tableview's section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `tableview` inside `viewcontroller (xib)` and `tableview` has `section header` and header view contains a `textfield`. If I scroll `tableview` manually and then open or hide keyboard (I mean click text field) then `tableview` automatically scrolls up and down respectively. It only happens when the textfield is in `section header view`. If I put the textfield outside of the `header view(section header)` then it is not happening.

So, **I want to stop that `autoscrolling` of tableview!**

I have checked many solutions, but none is working!

I have found that this is the usual case for `tableviewController` but I have `tableview` in `viewcontroller`!

If any body can help! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the issue of [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library. It scrolls tableview when textfield of header becomes firstresponder.

I have disable `IQKeyboardManager` manager for current class as solution like below,

```
  [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:NO];
```

and when leave current class I have again enable `IQKeyboardManager` like,

```
   [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
```